# Linguistic & cross-cultural perceptions of typography

Tags: perception, emotion, reading

**I have moved this question over from ux.stackexchange in the hope that it is a better fit for this forum and will get a few answers**

There is a great deal of information that one can find on the web which discusses the emotional impact that typography can have on the viewer.  To name two recent relevant articles

https://www.crazyegg.com/blog/psychology-of-fonts-infographic/
https://thenextweb.com/dd/2017/03/31/science-behind-fonts-make-feel/

I find myself wondering whether the broad conclusions presented in such articles has any validity when dealing with text in Arabic or in Indian or Far Eastern languages.  And then does the perception of typography for text presented in the latin alphabet change across cultures?  I have come across one study that is both interesting and relevant

https://cornerstone.lib.mnsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1670&context=etds

Perhaps there is someone on this forum who has studied these issues more thoroughly who might be able to comment?

---

Some very broad conclusions one can draw fro the Cornerstone study I mention above

- Common typefaces that have had a lot of exposure across the world are more likely to be perceived in the same way across cultures.
- The cross cultural receptiveness to sans serif typefaces is more uniform than serif typefaces
- While there can be broad agreement at the like/dislike level the evaluation of individual typeface traits - the author uses descriptors such as "professional" and "friendly" - can vary quiet markedly.
- Newer typeface innovations such as slab serif and geometric lead to greater difference in perception across cultures (this from the author's conclusion but I am unable to see where this was tested in the work in question)